# Making sure elements changed by javascript remain changed when user returns to page without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Sorry for the wonky title, had a hard time describing the problem. Also, sorry if this is duplicate it was hard to search for.

I'm trying to implement a relatively simply AJAX call on a button press using JQuery. My goal is to have a button that either says "Add to list" or "Remove from list" and, when pressed, makes an AJAX call to the server that adds/removes the item from the list appropriately. On success, the button is changed to reflect the change on the back end (so from Add to->Remove from and vice versa) by JQuery.

I'd like this to work even if the user doesn't have Javascript enabled (which is a good idea, right?) so my button is within a standard html form that makes a POST call, does the DB stuff, and then redirects the user to the webpage they were just on. I override this default behaviour with JQuery.

In order to display the correct button type when the user first loads the page, and also for when they do a standard POST call with Javascript enabled, I use Django's templating system to display the correct button/hidden values in the form.

This all works well and good... For the most part. The problem I'm having is when the user clicks the button using Javascript, then goes to another page, then uses the page back button to return to the page, the changes are not retained. That is, the button is displayed as it was rendered by Django on the first page load. This is fixed if the user reloads the page.

This, of course, is very confusing to the user as the button does not correctly reflect the state of the DB. How can I fix this?

Comment: how are you going to make an ajax call when javascript is disabled?

Comment: @chrisvillanueva he said he uses POST and server side code when javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no real good answer to this one.  The back button generally returns to a version of the page cached on the users browser, and interacts poorly with many forms of dynamic content.  You might consider trying to convince your users not to use the back button (made easier by a robust navigation bar or equivalent that they can use instead) or putting in a helpful note.  There are also various meta-tages you can put in to tell the browser not to cache the page (thus causing them to load it fully every time), but this can slow things down, and may not be followed by all browsers.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay. Thanks for the answer, it motivated a longer search on my own. Unfortunately, seems like you're right. For those looking at this in the future: there are also some things related to page state that can be accomplished using the location.hash. Unfortunately, not applicable to my site.